# why rail5 can't see the controller's modify when use the puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma, webrick

`evironment:
ruby2.3.1
rails5.0.1`

today i use the rails5 to build a new project,when id modify the action & refresh the browser,it doesn't show the change in immediately,then i `#gem 'puma'` & use the WEBrick server,it can show the change in immediately,did anyone konws why?

it's rails5 bug?

Comment: use the puma,I have to restart the server to see the changes immediately!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this line in your config/environments/development.rb

```
config.reload_classes_only_on_change = false
```

And also make sure the following line is present

```
config.cache_classes = false
```

This worked for me.